# how to show google map by full screen in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

in my angular app I use ngMap for google maps and show div with specific dimension (width:400px and height: 300px). Now, in some case, I need to show map in full screen. Is there any way to add double click or button or something else for this?

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var lokacije = [];
        id_maps = [];
        for (key in data.smart_es) {
            lokacije.push({
                lat: data.smart_es[key].lat, 
                lng: data.smart_es[key].lng

            });

        }
        $scope.lokacije = lokacije;

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 6,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.7007672, 15.4823411),
            //mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            styles: [{"featureType": "administrative", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [{"color": "#444444"}]}, {"featureType": "landscape", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [{"color": "#f2f2f2"}]}, {"featureType": "poi", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]}, {"featureType": "poi.business", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [{"visibility": "on"}]}, {"featureType": "road", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [{"saturation": -100}, {"lightness": 45}]}, {"featureType": "road.highway", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [{"visibility": "simplified"}]}, {"featureType": "road.arterial", "elementType": "labels.icon", "stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]}, {"featureType": "transit", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [{"visibility": "on"}]}, {"featureType": "transit", "elementType": "labels", "stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]}, {"featureType": "water", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [{"color": "#b2d0e3"}, {"visibility": "on"}]}]
        };

        $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);


//marker cluster

        //kraj marker cluster   

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        $scope.markers = [];
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


        var getSmartnchIcon = function (smartnch) {
            if (smartnch.type == 'urban') {
                return 'assets/img/marker_urban.png';
            } else {
                return 'assets/img/marker_standard.png';
            }
        };

        var createMarker = function (info) {
            selectednches = info;
           var nchTypeIconUrl = getSmartnchIcon(info);
                if(info.lat !== null && info.lng !== null){
                    $scope.latitude = info.lat;
                    $scope.longitude = info.lng;

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: $scope.map,
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng($scope.latitude, $scope.longitude),
                    optimized: false,
                    title: info.city,
                    icon: ypeIconUrl,
                    id: info.id

                });
                }else{
                    $scope.latitude = 43.5450037;
                        $scope.longitude = 16.4615604;

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: $scope.map,
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng($scope.latitude, $scope.longitude),
                        optimized: false,
                        title: info.city,
                        icon: ypeIconUrl,
                        id: info.id

                    }); 
                }
           marker.content =  '<div class="info-box-wrap">'
                                    +
                                    '<img src="" ng-click="openLightboxModal($index)"/>'
                                    +
                                    '<div class="info-box-text-wrap">'
                                    +
                                    '<h6 class="address">'
                                    +
                                    info.id + ' - ' + info.type
                                    +
                                    '</h6>'
                                    +
                                    '<p class="price">'
                                    +
                                    info.desc + '<br>'
                                    +
                                    info.last_report + '<br>'
                                    +
                                    '</p>'
                                    +
                                    '</div>'
                                    +
                                    '<div class="action-btns">'
                                    +
                                    '</div>' 
                                    + 

                                    '</div>'
                                    +
                                    '</div>' + marker.content;
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infoWindow.setContent('<div class="iw-title" style="color: #000;">' + '</div>' + marker.content);
                infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
            });
            $scope.markers.push(marker);
        };

        for (i = 0; i < lokacije.length; i++) {
            createMarker(lokacije[i]);
        }

        $scope.openInfoWindow = function (e, selectedMarker) {
            e.preventDefault();
            google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
        };
//marker clusterer
        var options = {
            imagePath: 'assets/img/i',
            gridSize: 50, 
            maxZoom: 10
        };
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer($scope.map, $scope.markers, options);


        $scope.clearMarkers = function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.markers.length; i++) {
                $scope.markers[i].setMap(null);
            }
            $scope.markers.length = 0;
        };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google maps offers the ability to show a fullscreen button check the [documentation about controls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#Adding_Controls_to_the_Map).

> The Fullscreen control offers the option to open the map in fullscreen mode. This control is enabled by default on mobile devices, and is disabled by default on desktop. Note: iOS doesn't support the fullscreen feature. The fullscreen control is therefore not visible on iOS devices.

So in your code you'd have to do this:

```
var mapOptions = {
     zoom: 6,
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.7007672, 15.4823411),
     //mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
     styles: [{"featureType": "administrative", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [{"color": "#444444"}]}, {"featureType": "landscape", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [{"color": "#f2f2f2"}]}, {"featureType": "poi", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]}, {"featureType": "poi.business", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [{"visibility": "on"}]}, {"featureType": "road", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [{"saturation": -100}, {"lightness": 45}]}, {"featureType": "road.highway", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [{"visibility": "simplified"}]}, {"featureType": "road.arterial", "elementType": "labels.icon", "stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]}, {"featureType": "transit", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [{"visibility": "on"}]}, {"featureType": "transit", "elementType": "labels", "stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]}, {"featureType": "water", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [{"color": "#b2d0e3"}, {"visibility": "on"}]}],
     fullscreenControl:true
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a fullscreen api you could use see [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API)

```
function toggleFullScreen() {
  if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
   document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
} else {
 if (document.exitFullscreen) {
  document.exitFullscreen(); 
}
```

}
}

Comment: thnx, I will use this definitely. But first, I want to see is there any solution in google maps.